# ws2_32.lib vs. libws2_32.a, what's the difference and how to link libws2_32 to NB project?

Tags: c++, dll, netbeans, linker, winsock2

I use NetBeans, Windows and Cygwin with g++ compiler.

I'm examining Windows Sockets 2. I do everything that is written in MS [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have a code (mostly from this manual):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {

  WSADATA wsaData;

  int iResult;

  // Initialize Winsock
  iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
  if (iResult != 0) {
     printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
     return 1;
  }
  else cout << "Initialization OK.";

  return 0;
}
```

And I have a problem when I try to run the project:

```
undefined reference to `_WSAStartup@8'
```

I understand that `Ws2_32.lib` is missing. This is because I do not have Windows SDK installed. But before installing it I want to try out tools that Cygwin offers. It has all the `w32api` header files, I have them in:

```
C:\cygwin\usr\include\w32api
```

And it has some `w32api` almost `.lib` files in the directory:

```
C:\cygwin\lib\w32api
```

But all these lib files are different, they have `.a` extension and a little bit different name, like:

```
libws2_32.a  // in Cygwin
   vs.
ws2_32.lib   // in Windows
```

When I use Cygwin terminal to create an `.exe` file, everything works fine. The commands I input are:

```
cd C:\\c++\\myProgram           // go to the dir
g++ myProgram.cpp -lws2_32      // compile using -l option to link libws2_32.a
```

And after it I get `a.exe` file. I run it and it works:

```
./a.exe    // Initialization OK.
```

But as I said I use NetBeans. And if I try to run the project from NB (`[F6]` button) I always have this error `undefined reference to '_WSAStartup@8'`.

I've tried already everything I could find on NB forums. I've tried to link `libws2_32.a` to my project this way. I go to:

```
File -> Project Properties -> Linker -> Libraries
```

And there are three options:

- Add Library...
- Add Library File...
- Add Option...

I've tried them all. I've tried to link both just Library and Library File. I've also tried 
to add such an option in the `Add Option...` button:

```
Add Option... -> Other option ->    // and I input here "-lws2_32"
```

But whatever I do I can't run the project from NB, I get error `undefined reference to '_WSAStartup@8'`.

So my questions are:

1) What do I do wrong? How may I run the project right from NB? I didn't try to install Windows SDK, I want to try with Cygwin tools as it has such kind of tools.

2) What is the difference between Windows `.lib` files and Cygwin `.a` files? Is it better to install Windows SDK and just forget about those `.a` files? Everything I could find so far about them on Cygwin site is this:

> The import library is a regular UNIX-like .a library, but it only
>   contains the tiny bit of information needed to tell the OS how your
>   program interacts with ("imports") the dll. This information is linked
>   into your .exe. This is also generated by dlltool.

3) Is it possible to use `#pragma comment(lib, "libws2_32.a")` to link `.a` files? I've tried but didn't get success results.

**UPD:**

The answer for the 3rd question -> [#pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib") equivalent under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685206/pragma-commentlib-xxx-lib-equivalent-under-linux)

Comment: @HansPassant, in fact that one absolutely does not duplicate my question. I read that post while being in search of the answers. Read questions with attention first before marking it as a duplicate.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. It seems to me that you've added the `-lws2_32` switch to the C/C++ compiler options. When netbeans invokes the compiler, it passes on the `-c` switch and it'll ignore the linker options, such as `-l`. In the linker options section, Netbeans has an apropriate place to add external libraries. Or you can add the `-l` as an extra option to the linker. That might solve the problem.
2. `*.lib` files are used by the Microsoft toolchain (cl.exe) and `lib*.a` are used by GNU toolchain (that's the piece of adivse you've found). If you're going to use Cygwin, you'll need the `lib*.a` files. In this context, having Microsoft SDK won't help you at all. Also, if you need a file that only exists in `.lib format, you can convert to`.a` with a tool called [reimp](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/MSVC_and_MinGW_DLLs).

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 9):

I had this problem Eclipse/CDT/Windows.
This is my build command

```
g++ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o source\Sever_B.o ..\source\Sever_B.cpp
g++ -LC:\MinGW\lib -o Sever_B.exe source\Sever_B.o -lws2_32
```

So on the Eclipse project properties, C/C++ General, Paths & Symbols

- Add C:\MinGW\lib to library paths tab
- Add ws2_32 to libraries tab

This links libws2_32.a to my project and it now builds OK.

I tried using the Windows ws2_32.dll and ws2_32.lib and got nothing but pain.