# undefined reference to '_WSAStartup@8'. How to link libraries with NetBeans?

Tags: c++, dll, netbeans, linker, winsock2

I use NetBeans, Windows and Cygwin with G++ compiler.

I'm examining Windows Sockets 2. I do everything that is written in MS [manual](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737629%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). I have a code (mostly from this manual):

```
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <ws2tcpip.h>

#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>

#pragma comment(lib, "Ws2_32.lib")

int main() {

  WSADATA wsaData;

  int iResult;

  // Initialize Winsock
  iResult = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2,2), &wsaData);
  if (iResult != 0) {
     printf("WSAStartup failed: %d\n", iResult);
     return 1;
  }
  else cout << "Initialization OK.";

  return 0;
}
```

And I have a problem when I try to run the project:

```
undefined reference to `_WSAStartup@8'
```

I understand that `Ws2_32.lib` is missing. This is because I do not have Windows SDK installed. But before installing it I want to try out tools that Cygwin offers. It has all the `w32api` header files, I have them in:

```
C:\cygwin\usr\include\w32api
```

And it has some `w32api` almost `.lib` files in the directory:

```
C:\cygwin\lib\w32api
```

But all these lib files are different, they have `.a` extension and a little bit different name, like:

```
libws2_32.a  // in Cygwin
   vs.
ws2_32.lib   // in Windows
```

When I use Cygwin terminal to create an `.exe` file, everything works fine. The commands I input are:

```
cd C:\\c++\\myProgram           // go to the dir
g++ myProgram.cpp -lws2_32      // compile using -l option to link libws2_32.a
```

And after it I get `a.exe` file. I run it and it works:

```
./a.exe    // Initialization OK.
```

But as I said I use NetBeans. And if I try to run the project from NB (`[F6]` button) I always have this error **undefined reference to '_WSAStartup@8'.**

I've tried already everything I could find on NB forums. I've tried to link `libws2_32.a` to my project this way. I go to:

```
File -> Project Properties -> Linker -> Libraries
```

And there are three options:

```
Add Library...
Add Library File...
Add Option...
```

I've tried them all. I've tried to link both just `Add Library...` and `Add Library File...`. I've also tried to add such an option in the `Add Option...` button:

```
Add Option... -> Other option ->    // and I input here "-lws2_32"
```

But whatever I do I can't run the project from NB, I get error **undefined reference to '_WSAStartup@8'.**

So it seems that it is not a problem (error) in the code. It seems that the problem is with NB, with its possibility to link libraries. Or I do wrong steps to attach them to the project.

So my questions are:

1) What do I do wrong? How may I run the project right from NB? I didn't try to install Windows SDK, I want to try with Cygwin tools as it has such kind of tools.

2) What is the difference between Windows `.lib` files and Cygwin `.a` files? Is it better to install Windows SDK and just forget about those `.a` files? Everything I could find so far about them on Cygwin site is this:

> The import library is a regular UNIX-like .a library, but it only
>   contains the tiny bit of information needed to tell the OS how your
>   program interacts with ("imports") the dll. This information is linked
>   into your .exe. This is also generated by dlltool.

3) Is it possible to use `#pragma comment(lib, "libws2_32.a")` to link `.a` files? I've tried but didn't get success results.

Comment: possible duplicate of [ws2_32.lib vs. libws2_32.a, what's the difference and how to link libws2_32 to NB project?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314779/ws2-32-lib-vs-libws2-32-a-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-link-libws2-32-to-n)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> 1) What do I do wrong? How may I run the project right from NB? I didn't try to install Windows SDK, I want to try with Cygwin tools as it has such kind of tools.

Try this: http://forums.netbeans.org/ptopic44959.html

> 2) What is the difference between Windows .lib files and Cygwin .a files? Is it better to install Windows SDK and just forget about those .a files?

Both of these files in this particular case are called "import libraries". Import libraries are basically a file containing a list of valid functions, so that when you link your exe, the linker knows that those functions will exist in some particular DLL. So when you link to wsock32.lib or ws2_32.lib, the linker now knows that these functions will exist in wsock32.dll and ws2_32.dll. Thus, it will not complain. Now, the .lib import library format is Microsoft's format. GCC/unix/linux/mingw/cygwin etc. have a different format, and the extension for that format is **.a**. Now, cygwin/mingw etc. provide a **ws2_32.a** so that when using cygwin/mingw/gcc, the linker can read the import library in the correct format. cygwin/mingw/gcc will simply not understand the **.lib**. Microsoft provides the **.lib** files in their SDK, but I am not sure how this will help in this case. (Though the SDK *is* definitely useful, because it provides lots of *header files* and DLLs for other useful things you might need, but the import libraries are useless, because gcc/mingw/cygwin will not understand them; unless you use a converter tool, like the one mentioned in your [duplicate question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12314779/ws2-32-lib-vs-libws2-32-a-whats-the-difference-and-how-to-link-libws2-32-to-n)).

> 3) Is it possible to use #pragma comment(lib, "libws2_32.a") to link .a files? I've tried but didn't get success results.

No, the #pragma linking comments are an MSVC specific (ugly IMO) extension. Use the linker options in the menus.

Comment: I have opened [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36520283/how-to-link-ws2-32-in-clion) I can't link `ws2_32` to my project. Please take a look if you know how to answer it

Answer (score 0):

eclipse, Cygwin

propeties -> C/C++ Build -> Settings -> Cygwin C Linker

Command line pattern

add to -lws2_32

ex)${COMMAND} ${FLAGS} ${OUTPUT_FLAG} ${OUTPUT_PREFIX}${OUTPUT} ${INPUTS} -lws2_32