# How to link ws2_32 in Clion

Tags: c++, cmake, mingw, boost-asio, clion

I am using Clion, which uses MinGW and Cmake. When I try to use the standalone `asio` library I am getting

```
undefined reference to `WSAStartup@8'
undefined reference to `WSASetLastError@4'
undefined reference to `closesocket@4'
...
```

I believe I have to link the `C:/Windows/System32/ws2_32.dll` library. I tried adding something like `-L C:/Windows/System32 -lws2_32`:

```
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -static -lws2_32")
```

But that didn't help. How can I fix these errors ?

Comment: You don't need `-L C:/Windows/System32` because mingw already has this library in it's distribution. Anyway, mingw can't link against `.dll`s, only `.a`s (and maybe `.lib`s).

Comment: I think the problem is that you put `-lws2_32` in the wrong variable, it must be in `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Where will I find the `.lib` or `.a` files ?

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I am clearly on a windows machine by the way

Comment: I'm telling you, this library is already distributed with the mingw. Just add `-lws2_32` flag to `CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS` variable.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I did: [image](https://i.gyazo.com/3f5f2d882b841a291debc1b1cdee5e56.png). Same error.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat I have these [2 libraries](https://i.gyazo.com/65c21715e942af237bd73f00ccc42cfd.png) in my MingGW/lib directory. Using `-llibws2_32` gives me linking error `cannot find -llibws2_32`. And `-lws2_32` gives me the same error as in my question. (`undefined reference`)

Comment: To get help with a failing linkage you need post at least the failing
linkage command, and the errors that ensue, verbatim from the build output. To get this from a CMake makefile, run `make VERBOSE=1`. The failing linkage command is the last `g++` command in the output.

Comment: @MikeKinghan I am using Clion. I don't understand what exactly you want me to do. I never touched Cmake. I only use CMakeLists.txt

Comment: @HolyBlackCat The correct way was to add `link_libraries(ws2_32 wsock32)`

Comment: I'm glad that you solved it. By the way, `lib` is added automatically to a library name. That's why `-llibws2_32` triggered a error. For example, `-lcat` means `link against libcat.a`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following CMakeLists.txt compiled error-less. Only 1 line is really required: `link_libraries(ws2_32 wsock32)`

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.3)
project(server_client)

set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11 -s -O3 -I C:/Users/Shiro/Desktop/asio-1.10.6/include")
set(CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS "${CMAKE_EXE_LINKER_FLAGS} ${GCC_COVERAGE_LINK_FLAGS} -static")
link_libraries(ws2_32 wsock32)


set(SOURCE_FILES chat_server.cpp)
add_executable(server_client ${SOURCE_FILES})
```