# How does the Cassandra C++ Driver use the zlib library?

Tags: c++, cassandra, datastax, zlib

The [Cassandra C++ Driver](https://datastax.github.io/cpp-driver/topics/building/) has an option used to enable the zlib library:

```
--ENABLE-ZLIB                     Enable zlib
```

Only they do not say what they are doing with it.

Anyone knows what that option gives us?

Does it *precompresses* the data before sending it to the backend? What else would it use zlib for? Looking at the source of the C++ driver, I can see the zlib option in the `CMakeLists.txt`:

```
option(CASS_USE_ZLIB "Use zlib" OFF)
```

But the C++ source has no `#include <zlib.h>` so I'm wondering whether there is any code actually using the library (maybe it was intended but never implemented?)

Comment: Maybe `#pragma (comment:lib)`?  [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685206/pragma-commentlib-xxx-lib-equivalent-under-linux)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The driver does not currently use zlib; it is there for future work. [CPP-103](https://datastax-oss.atlassian.net/browse/CPP-103) will add compression support to the driver which will utilize zlib at that time. It remained in the build system due to legacy implementation and can safely be ignored.

If you would like to see this feature implemented please vote or comment on the JIRA issue.

Comment: I see there is also an attempt by vhavel. How far along is that [github PR](https://github.com/datastax/cpp-driver/pull/413)?

Comment: The PR has been reviewed and code changes have been requested; however no updates have been made since the review was completed.