# Pragma ignoring comment [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]

Tags: c++, pragma

I'm trying to make function which will return version from FileVersionInfo,
so far i built funtcion, but i have issue when i want to include `version.lib`

```
#pragma comment(lib, "version.lib")
```

I have tried to link, `libversion.a`, something like this

```
#pragma comment(lib, "libversion.a")
```

but, again compiler was returning error like first time

> Pragma ignoring comment [-Werror=unknown-pragmas]

I have tried, many combinations from internet, i cant even remember all of them. I'm using MinGW compiler.
Thanks for your time i appricitate it :)

Comment: It doesn't look like GCC supports that particular pragma.

Comment: If it doesn't support it is there any alternative?

Comment: This pragma to link libraries from C++ source code is only supported (I think) by MSVC.

Comment: Specify the library you want to link against with the `-l` flag. [See here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Link-Options.html). You may need to use the `-L` flag to inform the linker about directories it needs to search for libraries.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [#pragma comment(lib, "xxx.lib") equivalent under Linux?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1685206/pragma-commentlib-xxx-lib-equivalent-under-linux) (The question asks about Linux but essentially it seems like it's about a GCC equivalent)

Comment: Also note that unknown-pragmas is only a warning, but it's being promoted to an error by `-Werror`. You can downgrade that diagnostic back down to a warning with `-Wno-error=unknown-pragmas`, or silence it altogether with `-Wno-unknown-pragmas`.

Comment: @NathanPierson did you mean like this '#pragma comment(lib, -l "libversion.a")' or something else if im not right can you provide me simple example

Comment: No, I meant that you need to use those as command-line arguments passed to your invocation of the linker, not in the source code at all.

Comment: Alright i'll give it a try

Comment: @NathanPierson what i tried is this "mingw32-make -j8 install -l libversion.a" in my build and install batch file, still same, also i tried to add -L and full path to libversion.a, still same (im stuck for like 2 days),  also i may be that im doing something wrong, or i maybe add sometong to my CMakeLists.txt

Comment: What are the contents of your makefile?

Comment: @NathanPierson https://pastebin.com/DRZq8Gqa CMakeList.txt pass: stack, (edited, wrong link)

Comment: Okay. I'm not familiar with CMake. You probably need to edit the sections titled `#Link libraries` or `#Library`, though. Does [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8774593/cmake-link-to-external-library) help?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237262/discussion-between-gmijo47-and-nathan-pierson). @NathanPierson

Comment: @prapin "*This pragma to link libraries from C++ source code is only supported (I think) by MSVC*" - MSVC is not the only compiler that supports this. C++Builder supports it, too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> "This pragma to link libraries from C++ source code is only supported by MSVC"

Switched compiler from gcc/g++ to MSVC, that's only solution :(

Comment: For GCC, you needed to add `-lversion` to linker flags.